# ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework with Abstraction Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to extend a project on PluralSight.  In this project I've got two tables in a database `Employees` and `Departments` with a 1 to many between `Departments` and `Employees`.  To keep the controllers from knowing about my `DbContext` I'm using the following interface:

```
public interface IDepartmentDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Employee> Employees { get;  }
    IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class DepartmentDb : DbContext, IDepartmentDataSource
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public DepartmentDb() :base("DefaultConnection") { }

    IQueryable<Employee> IDepartmentDataSource.Employees
    {
        get { return Employees; }
    }

    IQueryable<Department> IDepartmentDataSource.Departments
    {
        get { return Departments; }
    }

    //this is the part that's wrong I believe
    public void AddDepartment(Department dept)
    {
        this.Departments.Add(dept);
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
    //private readonly IDepartmentDataSource _db = new DepartmentDb();
    DepartmentDb _db = new DepartmentDb();

    public DepartmentController(DepartmentDb db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        var model = _db.Departments.Single(x => x.Id == id);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Department());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Department department)
    {
        _db.AddDepartment(department);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return View(department);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model eManager.Domain.Department
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Department"))
    {
            <fieldset>
            <legend>City</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

This seems like it's a good place to use the repository pattern (which I can't implement end to end).  But when I try to submit the form, I get an error saying that that parameters aren't being passed.  Why isn't MVC picking out the posted form values as parameters?

Comment: try this on your form...@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Department", null, FormMethod.Post))
{

Comment: @foxtrotZulu Still gives me the same error: it's just not picking the posted form values out.

Comment: ...so when you breakpoint your create POST action does it even make it to the action or the error happening before?

Comment: is error here ..._db.AddDepartment(department); with department = null?

Comment: By the way, if you really want to achieve an abstraction, you shouldn't expose the IQueryable in your interface (IDepartmentDataSource). Instead define GetById(), GetAll(), and the like.

Answer (score 1):

You're not buying yourself anything doing an abstraction like this. The API for `DbContext` is exposed to your controller actions, even if the actual `DbContext` class isn't. Changing to another ORM, WCF service, etc., will fundamentally impact your actions' code, regardless.

If you want a true abstraction create a repository or service class that will take an instance of `DbContext` in it's constructor, and then expose the results of a `DbSet` off that, through a custom API (i.e. don't just return the `DbSet` or queryable).

To connect these various repositories or services together so that you don't end up with multiple instances of your context, you'd traditionally create class to act as a unit of work, composed of repositories or services. However, by doing that you've essentially just created a matryoshka doll where you've a unit of work inside a repository inside a unit of work. I found the better approach here is to use a dependency injection framework with a per request scope lifetime manager for your context. That way, the same context instance is fed into each repository or service your DI container instantiates.

Similarly, I would steer you more towards services than repositories. It's mostly semantics, but a service should have more specific methods (`blogPostService.GetMostRecentPublishedPosts()` vs. `blogPostRepo.GetAll()`) and returns fully-baked data (no further querying needed), whereas a repository typically returns an unformed set of data that you would need to further filter, order, etc.

Comment: I was actually going to use a DI framework, but when I started this project nuget was down!  Can you elaborate on what you mean by a per request scope lifetime manager for your context?  Good advice on the service vs repository.

Comment: DI containers use lifetime managers to determine when they should create a new instance of something or reuse an existing instance. Depending on the particular framework, it might be called something else, but the concept is the same. Any good DI container intended to be used for web projects should have one that's a per request lifetime manager. That means that for the entire scope of the request, despite how many threads or process are in play, it will continue to use the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in 'FormCollection' instead and see what happens

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
    {
        // new up a viewmodel here or something
        var model = new Department();
        // database stuff
    }
```